# Angular 2: Default value dropdown selector

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to make a dropdown selector with Angular 2. I have an array of items  and they all get displayed just fine and the two way data binding works. My only problem is that the dropdown selector has no default value. The selector field is empty when I load the page. The selector is in a edit view of my application, thats why I want to match the default value with the value of the "entityToEdit.cluster.id" object. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
<select [(ngModel)]="entityToEdit.cluster"
            name="clusterSelector">
      <option *ngFor="let data of clusterData" [ngValue]= "data">
        {{data.id}}
      </option>
</select>
```

Comment: [(ngModel)]="entityToEdit.cluster['id']" should have been the ngmodel right?

Comment: No, I want to bind the entityToEdit.cluster object. I'm just displaying the objects in the selector by their id's.

Comment: But if you are showing the id for options,the default value should also be shown as id right?

Comment: yeah exactly :)

Comment: How does `clusterData` look and how does `entityToEdit` look like content wise?

Comment: Then you should be using this [(ngModel)]="entityToEdit.cluster['id']"

Answer (score 4):

Just set the default value on **`ngOnInit`**

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.entityToEdit.cluster ="defaultval";
}
```

Comment: entityToEdit.cluster is an object which holds the default value I want to show in the selector. Why should I alter its value?

Comment: it does not alter, it just set the initial value

Comment: yeah but the initial value i want to display is already in the entityToEdit.cluster object. The object is fine, it just doesnt show up as default value in my selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
Since you plan to show the selected id you should be setting the id as the ngmodel.
<select [(ngModel)]="entityToEdit.cluster['id']" 
                name="clusterSelector">
          <option *ngFor="let data of clusterData" [ngValue]= "data.id">
            {{data.id}}
          </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.